# npm - meaning of "Have you installed one of peer libraries?"

Tags: npm, material-ui

npm version: 5.6.0
While doing `npm install [package]` got the following sentence (warning?):

```
Have you installed one of peer libraries?
```

Is it a warning? What does it means?
Could not find it documented anywhere.

Example:

```
npm i material-ui-pickers
Have you installed one of peer libraries?
 > date-fns
 > luxon
 > moment
+ material-ui-pickers@1.0.0-rc.9
updated 1 package in 77.671s
```

Comment: Possibly just advertisement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `material-ui-pickers` > `package.json` under you node_modules folder, you will see that the message is a post-install message. As Sebastiaan stated, it's simply `material-ui-pickers` advertising other modules or potential dependencies when the installation is complete.

Comment: Thanks! but why this is needed? if material-ui-pickers consume those dependencies it needs to specify it in his package.json and that's it, no?

Comment: An oversight by the developer, looks like. The dependencies will be installed so this message can safely be ignored, as each entry within this post-install comment are part of the devDependencies in their .json file.